# Transforming an octagon with opposite edge identification

Tags: general-topology, polygons

So I'm, trying to glue the torus with 2 holes from the octagon, now I know how to do it from the octagon on the right (shown below) but I'm wondering how we can actually glue it from the octagon on the left (pairs are on opposite sides). Or is there a way to cut the octagon on the left to get the octagon on the right? I've tried multiple ways of cutting and pasting but I can't seem to make the octagon on the left into the one on the right. I think transforming the octagons might be simpler than the gluing.

[image]